# I am unable to get the Bootstrap Carousel working. It fails when I change the image source to an actual picture

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have done sufficient research and nothing provides me a directive / solution. I have experimented on the default example too. All is good until I change the source to an image.
![The image shows that the second slide does not display properly. The first and third are correct (the default code).][1]

Not allowed to post the image since I am new to Stackoverflow.

I have also tried

`<img data-src="01.jpg" alt="Second slide">`

Here is the Code:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">/li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img data-src="holder.js/1140x500/auto/#777:#555/text:First slide" alt="Firstslide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img data-src="01.jpg:#444/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/1140x500/auto/#555:#333/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change `data-src` to `src` in the `<image>` tag.

This should work fine

```
<img src="01.jpg" alt="Second slide">
```

You had a couple of unclosed tags as well.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gad676b/)